# How to match unordered things in pyPEG?

Tags: python, peg, pypeg

I have the following file:

```
orange
apple
orange
apple
apple 
lime
banana
```

Each type of fruit has a class to match it:

```
class Banana:
    grammar = ....

class Apple:
    ...
```

I have to match each fruit unordered, I cannot tell upfront what will be the order. How can I setup a `FruitBasket` grammar to match'em?

```
class FruitBasket:
    grammar = ?????
```

ps: The fruits are actually complicated rules, each fruit type stands for a different code block, such as a function, prototype, global variable, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [list](https://fdik.org/pyPEG/grammar_elements.html#lists):

> A `list` instance which is not derived from `pypeg2.Concat` represents different options. They're tested in their sequence. The first option which parses is chosen, the others are not tested any more. If none matches, a `SyntaxError` is raised.

For example:

```
from pypeg2 import K, List, maybe_some, parse

class Apple:
    grammar = K('apple')

class Banana:
    grammar = K('banana')

class Lime:
    grammar = K('lime')

class Orange:
    grammar = K('orange')

class FruitBasket(List):
    '''An unordered collection of zero or more fruits'''
    grammar = maybe_some([Apple, Banana, Lime, Orange])


if __name__ == '__main__':

    fruit = '''
        orange
        apple
        orange
        apple
        apple 
        lime
        banana
    '''

    print(parse(fruit, FruitBasket))
```

Output:

```
FruitBasket([<__main__.Orange object at 0x7ffa4991d8d0>, <__main__.Apple object at 0x7ffa49922c18>, <__main__.Orange object at 0x7ffa49927a58>, <__main__.Apple object at 0x7ffa499279b0>, <__main__.Apple object at 0x7ffa49927908>, <__main__.Lime object at 0x7ffa421ad828>, <__main__.Banana object at 0x7ffa421ad8d0>])
```